# scatter a vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

to plot a vector I am using something like:

```
plot(1:length(vector),vector)
```

Could scatter be used? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to plot only points, without lines connecting them, just specify the [marker and line style](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linespec.html) in the call to [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html):

```
plot(1:length(vector),vector,'o');  % Use a circle with no connecting line
```

Comment: @darkcminor: You already asked how to use SCATTER in your last question. SCATTER plots points, not lines. But PLOT can plot both or either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Scatter can be used in a similar fashion to plot.

```
scatter(1:length(vector),vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

`plot(vector,'o')` is a simpler way.